# how to store multiples records with some constraints?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, backend

I have one model called "Author".It has two attributes.

```
  firstName: {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true
    },
    lastName: {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true
    }
```

So i want to insert an array of author(firstName,lastName).So i used create method to store data.

```
create: function (req, res) {

        let  authors = req.body.author_name;
        let ids=[],i=0;    
        Author.create(authors,(err,author)=>{
            if(err)res.json('err');
            else res.json(author);
        });
}
```

in author_name = `[{'abc1','xyz1'},{'abc2','xyz2'}]`

it will work fine but **after** that when i enter

author_name = `[{'abc1','xyz1'},{'abc3','xyz3'}]`

it wont work.Because i mentioned that both first and last name should be unique.1st data of array is already in database But 2nd argument of array is not in database.So in the end nothing will stored .So i want to store that 2nd argument also.If some of data in array is **already** in **DB** then it shloud be ignored and other **data** should be **stored**.

So how to do that in better way(not looping if possible)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need execute find query for the input array, it brings already available records, then you need to exclude them from your input data then try to insert the unique data.

I hope it would help you.

Comment: Thanks ,but as i mentioned if there is possible way to insert data without using loop or another query then suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding how your database is functioning. No matter which db technology you are using, an `Author` object is represented by a single row or record. When you make both `firstName` and `lastName` unique fields, that means that first names can never be repeated, and neither can last names. So, for example, you could not have a "Bob Smith" and a "Sara Smith" because that would be repeating a last name.

In the records you are entering in your example, you are not providing a first or last name. It creates a single record with both `firstName` and `lastName` empty. Since these fields are unique, you are then not allowed to create any other authors with either first or last names empty.

I think you may need to think about whether you want these fields to be unique, and if storing it via an `Author` model is really what you want - I had a bit of trouble understanding what you mean by "storing the second argument" but "ignoring the first". Maybe you actually want to just store a list of names, not `Author` objects?

Comment: So i want to store all author's first and last name.But problem is that when any field of record gets repeated then it won't store all records.

Comment: I suspect that what you want is for the *combination* first/last name to be unique. If this is the case, I don't think you have any choice but to code it yourself: both to check the database before creating, and to check for duplicates in the new about-to-be-created records.

Comment: Thanks, So can you suggest any methods to do that or I just have to iterate through loop to check duplicates?